# Why is this not an example of Newton's third law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[Physics and Maths Tutor June 2018 QP - Paper 1 OCR (A) Physics A-level](https://www.physicsandmathstutor.com/pdf-pages/?pdf=https%3A%2F%2Fpmt.physicsandmathstutor.com%2Fdownload%2FPhysics%2FA-level%2FPast-Papers%2FOCR-A%2FPaper-1%2FJune%25202018%2520QP%2520-%2520Paper%25201%2520OCR%2520(A)%2520Physics%2520A-level.pdf)

Question 21(a) shows clothes at rest inside a washing machine and asks how this is not an example of Newton's third law. However, the question explains that the weight of the clothes is equal to the normal contact force of the clothes. Therefore, the normal contact force is equal and opposite to the gravitational force and are both acting on the clothes. This should be an example of Newton's third law.

Is there something i'm missing or is the question incorrect and is suppose to ask why this **is** an example of Newton's third law?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a book on a table not an example of Newton's third law?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28921/)

Comment: Consider the washing machine when it's running - the drum exerts a greater normal force to keep the clothes spinning, despite the fact that the clothes weigh the exact same as before. There are many scenarios where the normal force and the weight of the clothes may differ (i.e. when the clothes are accelerating up or down).

Comment: But the question explains that the clothes are at rest, which indicates that the washing machine is not running. Therefore, there should not be any increase in the normal force.

Comment: "This should be an example of Newton's third law." No. N3L is about any *interaction* between a pair of bodies. The law states that if body A exerts a force on body B, then B exerts an equal and opposite force on A. So the pairs of forces that N3L deals with are on different bodies. But the normal contact force on the clothes and the gravitational pull on the clothes both act on the clothes, so they can't be a Newton's third law pair of forces. [The normal contact force and the gravitational pull arise from quite different interactions, and each of these forces has its own N3L partner.]

Comment: @Am0000 A 3rd law pair of forces are *always* equal and opposite, but not all equal and opposite forces are 3rd law pairs. It doesn't matter whether the machine is or is not running (whether the forces are actually equal or not) - since the normal force and weight *can* differ, they *cannot* be a 3rd law pair.